# LiteDB import a csv

Tags: csv, opencsv, litedb

I don’t know how I can import a Csv to LiteDB.
I searched a lot but don’t get a solution. I’m using asp.net core 3.1 razor pages to build a one page website and I store my data in LiteDB. Now I have data to import, but I don’t know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new BsonArray(db.Engine.Find("mycol")));

db.Engine.Insert("mycol", JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json).AsArray.ToArray());
```

Comment: Ok, excuse me..I’m really new with programming so I will ask in detail: I got a model inventory and a model users. When a user has a item of inventory it’s not longer available for others... until user gives it back. So my data(Csv) has columns like “description”, “category” “user” etc. Will it work, when I push all columns like this code you post? And the second question: where I must write this code? In cshtml or what:) sorry I’m really new doing this